# TokenError: The code passed is incorrect or expired PASSPORT

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-twitter

Hello I have an error in my passport code:

```
The code passed is incorrect or expired.
500

TokenError: The code passed is incorrect or expired.
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/usr/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:329:12)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/usr/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:376:16)
    at /usr/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:166:45
    at /usr/app/node_modules/passport-github/lib/strategy.js:77:16
    at /usr/app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:209:7
    at passBackControl (/usr/app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:134:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

I have this problem on all computers except mine so I guess there is a token linked to my computer but not to the other ones.

This problem is present on twitter passport authentication

My strategies:

```js
const passport = require('passport')
const TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/User');
const keys = require('../config/keys')

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then((user) => {
        done(null, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: keys.twitter.consumerKey,
    consumerSecret: keys.twitter.consumerSecret,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:8080/auth/twitter/callback"
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  User.findOne({userid: profile.id}).then((currentUser) => {
    if(currentUser){
      done(null, currentUser);
    } else {
      new User({
        userid: profile.id,
        name: profile.displayName
      }).save().then((newUser) => {
        console.log('created new user: ', newUser);
        done(null, newUser);
      });
    }
  });
}));

module.exports = passport;
```

My routes:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passportTwitter = require('../auth/twitter');
const User = require('../models/User');

/* LOGIN ROUTER */
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', { title: 'Please Sign In with:' });
});

/* LOGOUT ROUTER */
router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

/* TWITTER ROUTER */
router.get('/twitter',
  passportTwitter.authenticate('twitter'));

router.get('/twitter/callback',
  passportTwitter.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/users');
  });

module.exports = router;
```

I know that this error is pretty common but I've been going from stackoverflow to github for 3 days to fix it and I'm not moving forward. So if you have a solution I would be very grateful.

If you want to try it yourself, I made a github: https://github.com/SPierre-Eloy/Passport_twitter_api/tree/master

EDIT : I reduced the code to isolate the problem to a single strategy, that of twitter.

Comment: Could you isolate the problem into a simpler example? We'd be able to help you better if you posted an example with one failing strategy. Also, include all files. Now there's ambiquity over mounts: Google strategy gets `/auth/github/callback` callback url, but the code is only registering `/github/callback`. There's only Github strategy configuration shown (copy & pasted twice).

Comment: I isolated the twitter strategy, which returns the same error. If you want to clone the files I made a github. https://github.com/SPierre-Eloy/Passport_twitter_api/tree/master

Comment: You know what, I tried your code. I commented out the mongo parts, and the authentication works alright!

Comment: It works, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.
It was MongoDB that posed problem, I temporarily removed it the time to find a lasting solution